# Installing browser apps in Websphere application server

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

I have an angular application that i want to deploy into websphere application server. Since a browser app doesn't have any code that needs to run on the server, and more specifically no java code at all, i can't really package it inside a war. The admin console doesn't allow me to use a zip file for installation.

[image: No option to upload zip]

I tried to manually add the folder to the `installedApps` directory and the `applications` directory. Neither of them are accessible from the browser. It's very simple in tomcat though. I just need to drop the folder into the `webapps` directory. Is there a direct analog to that in Websphere? Even an application server should expose some means of hosting static content right? (From the server's perspective my angular app IS static content)

[image: project structure]

I've pasted my project structure above.

One thing that does work is me making a blank java project and adding all these files to the `WebContent` folder. That doesn't help me though coz i have a build pipeline setup for the whole thing (with npm and browserify) and i don't want to mix packaging a war with it.

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Package it as a WAR or don't run it on a java application server.